# Adding table prefix to join in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have Codeigniter setup to add the prefix kms_ to my active record queries. However, I am trying to do a join with two ON conditions and it doesn't prepend them.

Right now I have to manually add them like so:

```
$this->db->join('site_items', 'kms_site_items.item_id = kms_items.id AND kms_site_items.site_id = 1', 'left');
```

Can I write this differently so that the table prefixes are added correctly?

Is there a way to get something like this to work:

```
$this->db->join('site_items', 'site_items.item_id = items.id AND site_items.site_id = 1', 'left');
```

Answer (score 6):

You can get the current database prefix manually like this:

```
$prefixed_tablename = $this->db->dbprefix('tablename');
```

So you could do this:

```
$this->db->join('site_items', $this->db->dbprefix('site_items') . '.item_id = ' . $this->db->dbprefix('items') . '.id AND ' . $this->db->dbprefix('site_items') . '.site_id = 1', 'left');
```

[Docs Here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/queries.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add `Prefix` table name like this :
for example your tables have `myPrefix_` as prefix and one of them might be `myprefix_user`.
After that in your `config/database.php` at the bottom of this page where you set your `database name`, `username` and `password`, You can see `dbprefix` and you can set your prefix as I mentioned above `myPrefix_`.
At the end, You can simply call your table name for example `$this->db->get('user')` and automatically Codeigniter set your prefix at the first of it.