# How to put multiple table prefix on CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, prefix

I have 2 groups of table which has different prefix, one of them has `int_` prefix
example : `int_employee_inner_circle` 

and another one has `ext_` prefix
example : `ext_employee_outer_circle`

Both table groups even with different prefix, needs to be joined for some use.

I was trying to search the solution, but the only way I found is just from [CI forum](http://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-61182.html) and to access both of those different database set, I must using [this method](http://www.kodingmadesimple.com/2014/06/connect-to-multiple-databases-in-codeigniter.html).

I was using CakePHP, and it can be magically done by setting the table prefix word inside the model class. So, whatever the prefix is, you just set it in the model class.

My question is, Is there any way and how to put different table prefix in one CI web application and it can be easily joined like usual CI's join query ?

I appreciate for any of your help, thanks.

Comment: u can use protected property in each model for different prefix. just suggestion.

Comment: Please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16021367/adding-table-prefix-to-join-in-codeigniter